# TailwindCSS + Alpine mobile navbar not working

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

I have everything working with one of the examples found on the website but for some reason I cannot seem to get the mobile navbar to show when clicking. Can someone take a peek and tell me what I'm missing please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css") %>"/>
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>
  </head>
  <div>
    <nav class="bg-gray-900">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between h-16">
          <div class="flex items-center">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
              <%= img_tag(Routes.static_path(@conn, "/images/logo.png")) %>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden md:block">
              <div class="ml-10 flex items-baseline">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Team</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Calendar</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Reports</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden md:block">
            <div class="ml-4 flex items-center md:ml-6">
              <button class="p-1 border-2 border-transparent text-gray-400 rounded-full hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700" aria-label="Notifications">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
                </svg>
              </button>

              <div @click.away="open = false" class="ml-3 relative" x-data="{open: false }">
                <div>
                  <button @click="open = !open" class="max-w-xs flex items-center text-sm rounded-full text-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-solid">
                    <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg">
                  <div class="py-1 rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical">
                    <a href="#" class="user-menu" role="menuitem">Your Profile</a>
                    <a href="#" class="user-menu" role="menuitem">Settings</a>
                    <a href="#" class="user-menu" role="menuitem">Sign out</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
<!-- code that is displayed when viewing mobile screens -->
          <div class="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
            <button @click="open = !open" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 focus:text-white">
              <svg class="block h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path x-show="open"  stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                <path x-show="!open" class="hidden" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div :class="{ 'block': open, 'hidden md:hidden': !open }" @click.away="open = false" x-data="{open: false}" x-show="open">
        <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 sm:px-3">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Team</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Calendar</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Reports</a>
        </div>
        <div class="pt-4 pb-3 border-t border-gray-700">
          <div class="flex items-center px-5">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
              <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="ml-3">
              <div class="text-base font-medium leading-none text-white">Tom Cook</div>
              <div class="mt-1 text-sm font-medium leading-none text-gray-400">tom@example.com</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-3 px-2">
            <a href="#" class="user-menu">Your Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="user-menu">Settings</a>
            <a href="#" class="user-menu">Sign out</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- end mobile screens -->
    </nav>
    <header class="bg-white shadow">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold leading-tight text-gray-900">
          Dashboard
        </h1>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <p class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><%= get_flash(@conn, :info) %></p>
        <p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><%= get_flash(@conn, :error) %></p>
        <%= @inner_content %>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</html>
```

I am working on getting this whole example in codepen to help things out and will update with that as soon as I have it working.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I never registered a state for the navbar and so it didn't fire the click event. The nav tag should be as:

`<nav class="bg-gray-900 x-data="{ open: false }">`

Answer (score 0):

I've got the mobile header working with the following code, I noticed that `open` doesn't get toggled on the mobile version so maybe this doesn't event need to be an Alpine.js component.

If this isn't exactly what you were looking for, feel free to leave a comment clarifying the behaviour you're after for the mobile navigation (currently I guess it just display everything on mobile breakpoints).

Note the I've gotten rid of `x-show` and the `:class` binding in favour of always applying the `md:hidden` class since I couldn't find where you wanted to toggle `open` from.

```html
<div class="md:hidden" @click.away="open = false" x-data="{open: false}">
  <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 sm:px-3">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Team</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Calendar</a>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Reports</a>
  </div>
  <div class="pt-4 pb-3 border-t border-gray-700">
    <div class="flex items-center px-5">
      <div class="flex-shrink-0">
        <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="ml-3">
        <div class="text-base font-medium leading-none text-white">Tom Cook</div>
        <div class="mt-1 text-sm font-medium leading-none text-gray-400">tom@example.com</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3 px-2">
      <a href="#" class="user-menu">Your Profile</a>
      <a href="#" class="user-menu">Settings</a>
      <a href="#" class="user-menu">Sign out</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above example is viewable/editable in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hugodf/pen/mdeXgzy?editors=1000).

Comment: I'll edit the post to show where the sizing takes place to show the hamburger style button to click on to show the menu. Here is a codepen with full example. When resizing for mobile you see the hamburger menu but it's not clickable. Some styling isn't correct from using Tailwind as CDN. https://codepen.io/willfore/full/dyYdBjd